# Скрипт в фоновом режиме. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Появилась нужда запустить скрипт в фоновом режиме. В интернете не нашёл именно то, что мне нужно. Есть код:

```
power = str(2**10000000)
file = open('calculated.txt','w')
file.write(power)
file.close()
```

(не стоит спрашивать зачем :D)
Если просто запустить скрипт и переключится на другое окно (не консоль), то получится так, что скрипт приостановит своё выполнение (т.е. расчёты) и начнёт только тогда, когда я снова переключусь на окно консоли. Мне же нужно, чтобы это всё выполнялось фоном. Желательно, чтобы даже не появлялось окно консоли, а скрылось, но это можно, думаю, при компиляции решить.

Заранее - благодарен за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно изменить расширение вашего скрипта на `.pyw`, тогда скрипт будет запущен не через `python.exe`, как обычно, а через `pythonw.exe`, тем самым, подавит окно консоли и скрипт будет лишь в процессах.

Answer (score 0):

> Появилась нужда запустить скрипт в фоновом режиме.

Запуск программ в фоновом режиме - задача системы, а не программы. Т.е. это система решает, кто и когда выполняется/приостанавливается. Если система остановила приложение: `killall -STOP yes`, то программа `yes` ничего не может с этим сделать.

Программа может, либо создать отдельный поток для параллельных вычислений, либо запустить другой процесс.

Еще есть отдельные "типы" программы: службы/демоны. Их запускает сама система, а не пользователь.

> Если просто запустить скрипт и переключится на другое окно (не консоль), то получится так, что скрипт приостановит своё выполнение

С чего вы взяли? Т.е. если вы музыку в плеере включите и переключитесь на блокнот, то музыка остановится?

> не появлялось окно консоли, но это можно при компиляции решить

При какой компиляции вы собрались решать этот вопрос? И каким образом?

Comment: 2-quote) С музыкой всё прекрасно, а вот с Python - нет. Как только я переключаюсь на другое окно, скрипт перестаёт выполнятся, как не странно.
3-qoute) Через PyInstaller. 

PyInstaller -w name_of_program.py

флажок -w отвечает за то, чтобы окно командной строки не появлялось при запуске .exe'шника